# Is there a python module that is good with graphics?

Tags: python, graphics, module

I'm looking all over and I can't find a decent graphics tool for like making games. NOT PYGAME! It would be best simpler than pyopengl but easier to understand than pygame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/).

The `pyglet.gl` module exposes an interface that uses OpenGL at lowest level to draw in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that [Cocos2D](http://cocos2d.org/) fits your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

...also do check out [PyOgre](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/PyOgre).